# What encoding is used by json.dumps?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding

When I use `json.dumps` in Python 3.8 for special characters they are being "escaped", like:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'Crêpes': 5})
'{"Cr\\u00eapes": 5}'
```

What kind of encoding is this? Is this an "escape encoding"? And why is this kind of encoding not part of the `encodings` module? (Also see [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/codecs.html),  I think I tried all of them.)

To put it another way, how can I convert the string `'Crêpes'` to the string `'Cr\\u00eapes'` using Python encodings, escaping, etc.?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#character-encodings?

Comment: Yes, does not seem to answer my question. Or is it unicode encoding? But I tried all python encodings, and I never got `Cr\\u00eapes`

Comment: I do not understand. The string `Crêpes` must be converted to the string `Cr\\u00eapes` somehow. This is implemented in python ONLY in the `json` module? Nowhere else?

Comment: JSON uses UTF-8 by definition. The standard encourages `\u00ea`-style escapes for non-ASCII characters, though. (Annoyingly, it requires the use of surrogates for code points outside the BMP.)

Comment: Ok, slow. Now you talk about surrogates and code points. 

Is there an EASY to understand tutorial which explains all of that?

Comment: The trivial solution is to load it back in using `json.loads()`

Comment: Surrogates are an esoteric detail of Unicode. The original 16-bit encoding was extended and a dedicated area was assigned for encoding code points outside the original code space (the Basic Multilingual Plane) where you have to use two 16-bit values to encode a single character (where Unicode prefers the term "code point" over the heavily ambiguous and sometimes imprecise "character" for one value which can be encoded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably confused by the fact that this is a JSON string, not directly a Python string.

Python would encode this string as `"Cr\u00eapes"`, where `\u00ea` represents a single Unicode character using its hexadecimal code point. In other words, in Python, `len("\u00ea") == 1`

JSON requires the same *sort of* encoding, but embedding the JSON-encoded value in a Python string requires you to double the backslash; so in Python's representation, this becomes `"Cr\\u00eapes"` where you have a literal backslash (which has to be escaped by another backslash), two literal zeros, a literal `e` character, and a literal `a` character. Thus, `len("\\u00ea") == 6`

If you have JSON in a file, the absolutely simplest way to load it into Python is to use `json.loads()` to read and decode it into a native Python data structure.

If you need to decode the hexadecimal sequence separately, the `unicode-escape` function does that on a byte value:

```
>>> b"Cr\\u00eapes".decode('unicode-escape')
'Crêpes'
```

This is sort of coincidental, and works simply because the JSON representation happens to be identical to the Python `unicode-escape` representation. You still need a `b'...'` aka `bytes` input for that. (`"Crêpes".encode('unicode-escape')` produces a *slightly* different representation. `"Cr\\u00eapes".encode('us-ascii')` produces a `bytes` string with the Unicode representation `b"Cr\\u00eapes"`.)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. But when I do e.g. `"Crêpes".encode("unicode-escape")` I get the bytes `b'Cr\\xeapes'`. This means that `\x` is the equivalent to `\u00`? Or how could that be expressed? If `\u` is the unicode encoding, what is `\x`?

Comment: In Python 3, they are essentially equivalent. In Python 2, `\xea` was literally the byte with that value.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a Python encoding. It is the way JSON encodes Unicode non-ASCII characters. It is independent of Python and is used exactly the same for example in Java or with a C or C++ library.

The rule is that a non-ASCII character in the Basic Multilingual Plane (i.e. with a maximum 16 bits code) is encoded as `\uxxxx` where xxxx is the unicode code value.

Which explains why the `ê` is written as `\u00ea`, because its unicode code point is U+00EA